# Selenium with PhantomJs webdriver

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I've just added Selenium via NuGet (version of Selenium 2.42), and can't see HideCommandPromptWindow for PhantomJs (according to this: [Selenium Webdriver PhantomJS C# always opens a cmd window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711407/selenium-webdriver-phantomjs-c-sharp-always-opens-a-cmd-window). How to get it working (my script works fine, except I want to hide cmd window).

Comment: Looks like `driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow` from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21949015/1816580) is still there. What is the error that you're experiencing?