# How can I start PhantomJS + Selenium window in background?

Tags: c#, selenium, phantomjs

I'm using selenium + phantomjs in my application, but I want to start my application, selenium and phantomjs window in background. How can I do it?

I tried:

```
PhantomJSOptions options = new PhantomJSOptions();
options.AddAdditionalCapability("start-maximized", false);
IWebDriver driver = new PhantomJSDriver(Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\drivers", options);
```

Comment: Ohh Sorry.. When I start my application I want to start phantomjs in background.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. PhantomJS is headless, so there is no window that is opened. What window are you talking about?

Comment: When I declare a webdriver with type as Phantomjs, a new Console open in the screen.I have searched about it, and I can hide this console but when I do that, my application stop working until phantomjs stop.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Selenium Webdriver PhantomJS C# always opens a cmd window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711407/selenium-webdriver-phantomjs-c-sharp-always-opens-a-cmd-window)

Comment: No, My problem is like this one,I can hide the console application but when I hide, like I said, my application stop working..How can I fix that?

Comment: So you tried it already with `driverService.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;` and it didn't work?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. It hide the Console. But My application does not focus. My application stop working until phantomjs do all what it have to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var serviceJs = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService(phantomPath);
serviceJs.HideCommandPromptWindow = true;

Instance = new PhantomJSDriver(serviceJs);
```