# How to parse a site that returns a different HTML <title>Please wait 5 seconds...</title>

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, request

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL="https://kissanime.to"
page = requests.get(URL)

Code = BeautifulSoup(page.content,"html.parser")
print Code.title
```

This is the output

```
<title>Please wait 5 seconds...</title>
```

Every time i request from this site this is the only thing i get. Is there a way to get around this and get the HTML code from the actual site?

I want to get:

```
<title>KissAnime - Watch anime online in high quality</title>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This particular website is quite dynamic and it needs a *real browser* to be loaded in. Let's control [`PhantomJS` headless browser](http://phantomjs.org/) through the [`selenium`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) WebDriver, load the page and [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) for the title not to be equal "Please wait 5 seconds...":

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS()
driver.get("https://kissanime.to")

# wait for title not be equal to "Please wait 5 seconds..."
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(lambda driver: driver.title != "Please wait 5 seconds...")

print(driver.title)
```

Prints:

```
KissAnime - Watch anime online in high quality
```

Comment: i downloaded selenium and PhantomJS but i keep getting a path error that i can't figure out how to fix.                                                      WebDriverException: Message: 'phantomjs' executable needs to be in PATH.                                                                                                                         Where should i put phantomjs?

Comment: @forest203 well, this certainly goes out of scope of this particular topic. If you cannot solve it on your own or find a solution on the web, see if it makes sense to create a separate question here on SO. Thanks for understanding.

Comment: path=r'C:\Users\Forest\Desktop\New folder\phantomjs-2.1.1-windows\bin\phantomjs.exe'                                                                           driver.PhantomJS(executable_path=path)                                                          did not know you needed an r before the path

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to have phantomJS black box not show up when i run this?

Comment: @forest203 interesting question, there is a C# specific solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711407/selenium-webdriver-phantomjs-c-sharp-always-opens-a-cmd-window. See if it makes sense to create a python+selenium+phantomjs specific question about it. Thanks.