# Hiding the CMD window of PhantomJS on python with selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, python-3.6

I am trying to hide the CMD window that appears when launching PhantomJS with python:

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.PhantomJS()
```

There appears to be a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20711407/selenium-webdriver-phantomjs-c-sharp-always-opens-a-cmd-window#_=_) when working with C#, however, I was not able to find anything similar for python. Since the feature for C# was added  back in 2014, I assume something similar should exist for python too.

I'm using latest PhantomJS and Python 3.6.2.

This is how it looks like:

[image: PhantomJS.exe opens up]

Comment: Maybe this can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25871898/how-to-hide-chromedriver-console-window ?

Comment: Perhaps I don't understand how you are launching your code but I have no additional cmd windows open when I use PhantomJS. I do have the original  cmd windows of course, the one I used to run the script from. If I launch the script by clicking the python file, it will bring up a cmd window but that's just a regular cmd, not phantomjs related.

Comment: Can you show us a snap of the CMD window?

Comment: Added a screenshot for clarity

Answer (score 0):

For me,
The below code works fine.

```py
driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(
    service_args=service_args,
    desired_capabilities=caps,
    executable_path='phantomjs.exe',
    service_log_path=None
)
```

Here you have to add service_log_path=None for no log file that's why the console window will get hidden.

**Still Not solved then**

*replace code from*

(*C:\Users\YOUR_USER_NAME\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py*) file

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, env=self.env, close_fds=platform.system() != 'Windows', stdout=self.log_file, stderr=self.log_file, stdin=PIPE)
```

to

```
self.process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdin=PIPE, stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE, shell=False, creationflags=0x08000000)
```